# LT3663-5 with 5V and 3.3V output, can RTN be connected to common ground on circuit board?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, circuit-design

I'm making an automotive circuit where both 5V and 3.3V is needed. I'm planning to use LT3663-5 and 1761ES5-3.3 to create those voltages.

Now my question is, whether it is safe to connect RTN on 3v3 output to common ground?
(See example at: https://www.arrow.com/en/reference-designs/typical-application-for-lt3663ems8e-5-5v-step-down-regulator-with-isolated-33v-output/4c40a44cc9a9bb46946efb3da9dc5c84)

I'm using those voltages to feed micro controller board (5V (but 3V3 logic)), CAN controller (3V3)(MCP2515) and CAN Bus interface (5V) (TJA1050)

I believe that those all need the same ground level in order to work together.

---

Thank you for your answers, they were very helpful. Based on ideas presented here, I came up with the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sub>Image source - [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjuODI4SHz8PglP0QCvRYVMQp8Lj?e=48asu2)</sub>

I added also reverse polarity protection to the circuit. How does it look?

Comment: John D has answered it.  Just wanted to expand on, if you aren't going to use the isolation, save money and space by just using the 1761ES5-3.3 as a post regulator to the 5V. Much simpler!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe.  The 3.3V output is isolated, so you can connect its ground wherever you want.  However, it's not clear why you would want an isolated topology if you are just going to connect the grounds together.  Depending on the current required you could derive the 3.3V from the 5V using an LDO or a small switcher and avoid the need for a transformer.